# How to add custom framework to Firemonkey iOS project

Tags: ios, facebook, delphi, frameworks, firemonkey

I'm trying to add the iOS `FacebookSDK` to my `Firemonkey` application, this is what I've done so far:

1. Add new record to SDK manager. Local cache updated. "Include subdirectories" also checked, because Facebook library file located at Versions/A path in the SDK package.
2. In the bridge file I add the path:

`libFacebookSDK = '/System/Library/Frameworks/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK';`

3. Then I try to load the library:

`dlopen(MarshaledAString(libFacebookSDK), RTLD_LAZY);`

4. Everything compiles successfully.

**But** when I start the app I have the following error:

> Can't load FacebookSDK library: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK, 1): image not found

Where is the error? Could it be that Firemonkey doesn't deploy the framework to the iPhone?

Comment: And it doesn't say what image?

Comment: @Jerry Dodge, thanks for the response. dlerror returns only message, which I specified. And SDK consists of only from one library...

Answer (score 0):

In several occasions I have experienced that the "Update local cache" function does not work with manually added frameworks (In my own Delphi XE7 update 1). You can however update the cache manually.

Simply copy the framework from the Mac to the cache folder. 
Depending on the iOS version and target it is here on Windows:
MyDocuments\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS7.1.sdk\System\Library\Frameworks

Comment: thanks for response. Framework exists ins the SDK folder. But how I can check it on iPhone? - Is framework was copied?